Dynamically create and destroy (sub)nodes from one running instance of (main)node in rclpy?
In rclcpp, I use node->create_sub_node() to dynamically create nodes under the namespace. And I am looking for something similar for the rclpy. I couldn't find inbuild functionality, but if someone knows an interesting technique to fulfill this without any built-in function?
The basic explanation would be I have the main node spinning, and I would like to create and destroy (sub)nodes dynamically based on some main node's activity.
Let me know if you need more details.
[ROS 2 Humble, Ubuntu 22.04]

At the end I ended up using Executors. To be specific, MultiThreadedExecutor(). Below is the code sample for logic in case if anyone have similar usecase. There can be other variations (May be more optimal as well). Do not hesitate to suggest if you have some better solutions.
This is purely for logic.
import rclpy
from rclpy.node import Node
from std_srvs.srv import Empty
from rclpy.executors import MultiThreadedExecutor
from std_msgs.msg import String
from typing import Dict


class MySubNode(): # one can directly use MySubNode(Node): instead of passing node as an argument
    def __init__(self,node:Node):
        self.publisher_ = node.create_publisher(String, 'topic', 10)
        timer_period = 0.5  # seconds
        self.timer = node.create_timer(timer_period, self.timer_callback)
        self.i = 0
    def timer_callback(self):
        msg = String()
        msg.data = 'Hello World: %d' % self.i
        self.publisher_.publish(msg)
        self.get_logger().info('Publishing: "%s"' % msg.data)
        self.i += 1 
        
class MyMainNode(Node):
    def __init__(self, executor):
        super().__init__('main_node')
        self.executor = executor
        self.add_node_srv = self.create_service(Empty,'add_node',self.add_node)
        self.rmv_node_srv = self.create_service(Empty,'rmv_node',self.rmv_node)
        self.i = 1
        self.nodes: Dict[str,Node] = {}
        
    def add_node(self, request, response):
        name = f'node_{self.i}' # ofc you can use requested name
        node = rclpy.create_node(name, namespace=name) # imp to assign new ns for each node
        self.nodes[name] = node
        MySubNode(node)
        self.executor.add_node(node)
        self.i+=1
        return response
        
    def rmv_node(self, request, response):
        self.i-=1
        name = f'node_{self.i}' # ofc you can use requested name
        self.executor.remove_node(self.nodes[name])
        self.nodes[name].destroy_node()
        self.nodes.pop(name)
        return response
        
def main(args=None):
    rclpy.init(args=args)
    executor = MultiThreadedExecutor()
    # You may ask why passing executor as an argument and not creating in the class?
    # I tried that but it was always returning the None type object instead
    node = MyMainNode(executor)
    node.executor.add_node(node)
    try:
        node.executor.spin()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        for node in node.executor.get_nodes():
            node.destroy_node()
    rclpy.shutdown()

